# Coldfusion Github webhook library or sample code

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

Is there a Coldfusion library or sample code that whenever you make a commit to the master branch of your github repo, The webhook will trigger and pull the master branch.

Comment: This is not a Coldfusion or Lucee question, it is a question about Git and Github, so you might want to re-label it. Coldfusion and Lucee have nothing to do with your code repo.

Comment: @andrewdixon I think it's meant as "how do I implement a webhook listener in Coldfusion" (and git only being the circumstantial target here)

Comment: A webhook is nothing but a URL (in this case based on a ColdFusion page) that can accept POST requests and does something based on the posted data. If you can create a CF page that can accept a form POST, you can create a webhook receiver. If you have a *specific* problem, you must specify your question.

Comment: @vlad if you want to know about GITHUB API details then you have to check below docs. https://developer.github.com/v3/ as per andrewdixon .

Comment: I was thinking by setting up a webhook when I do a commit from the repository it would trigger the github webhook to my coldfusion page and inside the Coldfusion script I would execute git command to pull and deploy the recent commit. 
I'm asking for a sample code as a starting point or maybe someone already have done it. I saw a sample where after executing git a zip file is downloaded and unzipped to his wwwroot but I don't want to do it that way coz that's a lot file size and heavy load for let say 1 file change.